# setSupportActionBar inside of a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have a Fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() { ... }
```

Now I'm trying to add an Actionbar to it, but this doesn't work:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main))
```

How can I set the Support and then add Items to the ActionBar?

This is how it works in an AppCompatActivity:

```
//    This adds items to the ActionBar
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar_main, menu)
        return true
    }


//    This is the OnClickListener for the Buttons in the ActionBar
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.toolbar_edit -> {


        true
    }

    R.id.toolbar_search -> {


        true
    }

    else -> {
        // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
        // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your `Fragment` and inflate your `menu` inside. Than in `onCreate` method of `Fragment` set `setHasOptionsMenu()` to true. To inflate different menus depending on `Fragment` creation `clear` the menu first.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater?.inflate(Your menu here, menu)
}
```

Comment: But if I try to inflate in the Fragment it says that menuInflater has an unresolved reference. Can you please give me an example on how to do it?